# Laravel imagecopy lowers image quality

Tags: php, laravel

I am coding a Laravel project where I let users add their own small image to a bigger image (something like milliondollarhomepage.com).
I use the PHP `imagecopy();` to add the small image to the bigger image. The problem is: the colors get really poor after merging the two images together. I think the new image only has the colors of the previous image, so no new colors can be added to the image.

My code:

```
$pixel = GET_INFO_HERE;

$dest = imagecreatefrompng(public_path('storage/pixels.png'));//get big image
$src = imagecreatefrompng(public_path('storage/uploads/' . $pixel->imagename));//get small image to add

imagecopy($dest, $src, $pixel->x_position, $pixel->y_position, 0, 0, $pixel->width, $pixel->height);

ob_start();
imagepng($dest);
$newpixelsimg = ob_get_clean();

Storage::put('public/pixels.png', $newpixelsimg);//save new image

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

I tried to use `imagetruecolortopalette($dest, false, 255);` before the `imagecopy();` method, but it didn't change anything.

I have been searching for solutions for a long time now, but I couldn't get it to work yet.
Is there anyone who has a solution for this?

Comment: why don't you use http://image.intervention.io/

Comment: I just tried to use that, but the color problem stays the same :(

Comment: Lmao it works now. You're a god, thank you!